# Restric GCP API Key To A Subset Of Endpoints For A Given API

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-error-reporting

As per the docs on [Adding API Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_api_restrictions) to API keys, I have specified a single GCP API that I'd like a particular API key to be able to operate on (in my case; Error Reporting).

However the [Error Reporting REST API](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest) has a lot of capabilities that I'd rather not allow this API key to operate on ... in fact, there's only a single endpoint in that REST API that I'd like to allow my API key to call.

Thus, how do I restrict an API key to only access a subset of endpoints for a given GCP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Error Reporting API, if you want to further restrict the API Key so that it can only call certain methods of the REST API, then further restrictions can be added to the API key by optionally specifying the methods in the [Error Reporting service](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys#add-api-restrictions).

Comment: Your response is regarding Google's "endpoint" service ... which is not what I'm asking about. To clarify, I'm asking about limiting REST API access for one of GCP's own API's such as the GCP Error Reporting API.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check once if this solves your issue.